# Adding multiple images with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having problems uploading multiple files using paper clip.
I've tried to follow this guide here
[guide](http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/)

The structure of my models are:

A user has_many trip_images

then trip_images has_attached_file :photo

I don't get any errors when trying to upload a new photo(s) but I can't make them display on a users show view. I'm pretty sure that it's more than just the view that's wrong here.

error:

```
unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end '; @trip_images do |t| ^ C:/row/map/app/views/user/show.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

So far this is what I have.

user.rb

```
has_many :trip_images, :dependent => :destroy
```

trip_image.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_attached_file :photo
validates_attachment_presence :photo
```

user_controller.rb

```
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @trip_images = @user.trip_images
      end
          ...    
      def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
          if params[:photos]
              params[:photos].each { |photo|
              @user.trip_images.create(photo: photo) }
          end
            redirect_to(:action => 'index')

        else
          render('new')
        end
      end
... 

private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :trip_images, :photo)
    end
```

trip_images_controller.rb *removed*

```
    def index

        @user = user.find(params[:user_id])

        @trip_images = @user.trip_images

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @trip_images }
        end
      end

      # GET /trip_images/1
      # GET /trip_images/1.json
      def show
        @trip_image = trip_image.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @trip_image }
        end
      end

      # GET /trip_images/new
      # GET /trip_images/new.json
      def new
        @user = user.find(params[:user_id])
        @trip_image = @user.trip_images.build

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @trip_image }
        end
      end

      # GET /trip_images/1/edit
      def edit
        #@user = user.find(params[:user_id])

        @trip_image = trip_image.find(params[:id])
        # @trip_image = trip_image.find(params[:id])
      end

      # POST /trip_images
      # POST /trip_images.json
      def create
        @trip_image = trip_image.new(params[:trip_image])

        if @trip_image.save
          respond_to do |format|
            format.html {
              render :json => [@trip_image.to_jq_upload].to_json,
              :content_type => 'text/html',
              :layout => false
            }
            format.json {
              render :json => [@trip_image.to_jq_upload].to_json
            }
          end
        else
          render :json => [{:error => "custom_failure"}], :status => 304
        end
      end
....
 private

  def trip_image_params
    params.require(:trip_image).permit(:description, :user_id, :photo)
  end
```

User/show.html.erb

```
<% @trip_images do |t| %> 
  <%= t.photo_file_name %>
  <%= image_tag t.photo_url %>
<% end %>
```

So in the end run I want users to upload photos and then have them be visible on their respective "show" view.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

- No need for a TripImages controller - you're rendering from Users
- Modify User/show.html.erb:

`<% @trip_images do |t| %> 
  <%= t.photo_file_name %>
  <%= image_tag t.photo_url %>
<% end %>`

This is a nice article on this topic: http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/

Chapter 9 of 'Rails 3 in Action' by Katz and Bigg covers implementation step-by-step. There are numerous pdfs available online.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the article is what I was trying to follow :p It's throwing me this syntax error though. `unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end '; @trip_images do |t| ^ C:/row/map/app/views/user/show.html.erb:22: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: The following should be in your User model: accepts_nested_attributes_for :trip_images, :allow_destroy => true`